# Convert List to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Dictonary**:

```
{(8758148.0, 'CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund'): D    0.000016
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI American Growth Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI American Small Companies Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI American Value Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Equity Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Investment Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Small Cap Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Small/Mid Cap Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI Global Bond RSP Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64,
 (8758148.0, 'CI Harbour Fund'): D    0.0
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64 }
```

I need the dataframe to be:

```
id          Name                                Value 
8758148.0   CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund        0.000016
```

I am stuck in issue where I need to convert list into such a data frame with certain name of the columns

Comment: Do you mean your dictionary looks like this? `{(8758148.0, 'CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund'): 'D    0.000016
 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64'`

Comment: yes actually its two key dictionary

Comment: can you plz modify the code to something that works? will save us from the guessing...keep the code in the code block...the question as separate

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. I modified the string a bit, so that it can be saves as a dictionary.

```
g = {(8758148.0, 'CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund'): 'D    0.000016 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI American Growth Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI American Small Companies Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI American Value Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Equity Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Investment Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Small Cap Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI Canadian Small/Mid Cap Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI Global Bond RSP Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64',
 (8758148.0, 'CI Harbour Fund'): 'D    0.0 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64' }
```

Now here is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i[0] for i in g.keys()], columns=['id'])
df['Name'] = [i[1] for i in g.keys()]
df['Value'] = [i.split()[1] for i in g.values()]
df

    id          Name                            Value
0   8758148.0   CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund    0.000016
1   8758148.0   CI American Growth Fund 0.0
2   8758148.0   CI American Small Companies Fund    0.0
3   8758148.0   CI American Value Fund  0.0
4   8758148.0   CI Canadian Equity Fund 0.0
5   8758148.0   CI Canadian Investment Fund 0.0
6   8758148.0   CI Canadian Small Cap Fund  0.0
7   8758148.0   CI Canadian Small/Mid Cap Fund  0.0
8   8758148.0   CI Global Bond RSP Fund 0.0
9   8758148.0   CI Harbour Fund 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy though I solve it the other way but appreciate your response :)

Comment: Please mark the solution you used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to make up a simple example which you can modify to your own example. This is a generic approach that can be used for any similar operations.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {('a', 'b'): 1, ('c', 'd'): 2}
x=pd.DataFrame(d.items(),columns=['keys','value'])

def extract(x):
  (key1,key2)=x['keys']
  x['key_1']=key1
  x['key_2']=key2
  del x['keys']
  return x

x.apply(lambda x: extract(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: PandasError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-62456204fae4> in <module>()
      1 d = Final
----> 2 x=pd.DataFrame(d.items(),columns=['keys','value'])
      3 
      4 def extract(x):
      5   (key1,key2)=x['keys']


PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your error. Can you check for any pasting errors?

Comment: This dictionary is more complex, each item is like this: (8758148.0, 'CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund'): 'D 0.000016 Name: 8758148.0, dtype: float64'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [178]: pd.DataFrame([[k[0], k[1], v.split()[1]] for k,v in d.items()],
                       columns=['id','Name','Value'])
Out[178]:
          id                              Name     Value
0  8758148.0      CI Alpine Growth Equity Fund  0.000016
1  8758148.0           CI American Growth Fund       0.0
2  8758148.0  CI American Small Companies Fund       0.0
3  8758148.0            CI American Value Fund       0.0
4  8758148.0           CI Canadian Equity Fund       0.0
5  8758148.0       CI Canadian Investment Fund       0.0
6  8758148.0        CI Canadian Small Cap Fund       0.0
7  8758148.0    CI Canadian Small/Mid Cap Fund       0.0
8  8758148.0           CI Global Bond RSP Fund       0.0
9  8758148.0                   CI Harbour Fund       0.0
```

where `d` is your dictionary